# Self join on a query invalid object Name MSSQL 2008

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to do a self join on this query and keep getting the error `invalid object name x`

```
select row_number() over(order by patientid,admissiondate, claimsfromdate,datediff(dd,admissiondate, claimsfromdate)) as rn
    ,x.patientid, x.admissiondate, x.claimsfromdate, x.rehabwait

from
(
SELECT distinct 
        patientid
        ,admissiondate
        ,claimsfromdate
        ,DATEDIFF(dd, admissiondate, claimsfromdate) as rehabWait, hcpcs
FROM    Claims
WHERE   hcpcs in ('g0151', '97001', '97002', '9339') and claimsfromdate > admissiondate
) x inner join x as x2 on x.patientid=x2.patientid
```

I can't do this without saving it as a view or rewriting the query out twice (once in the from, once in the inner join), can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE:

```
with x as (
     SELECT distinct patientid, admissiondate, claimsfromdate,
            DATEDIFF(dd, admissiondate, claimsfromdate) as rehabWait, hcpcs
     FROM    Claims
     WHERE   hcpcs in ('g0151', '97001', '97002', '9339') and
             claimsfromdate > admissiondate
    )
select row_number() over (order by patientid, admissiondate,
                                   claimsfromdate,
                                   datediff(dd,admissiondate, claimsfromdate)
                         ) as rn,
       x.patientid, x.admissiondate, x.claimsfromdate, x.rehabwait
from x inner join
     x as x2
     on x.patientid=x2.patientid
```

Having fixed your original problem, I do not see what you are using x2 for.  It doesn't appear in the "SELECT" statement.  All you are doing is creating a cross product of all claims for a given patient.  Perhaps this is reasonable.  I would expect a group by to be part of such a query.

Comment: this was the first part of a two part question.  My entire intention was to join x2 on patientID and x2.rn > x.rn to have a running total of substraction.  http://imgur.com/yCN5U where row number would read 60 (62-32) and row 3 60 (152-92).  Having trouble with that one, too  but still working on it :)

Comment: this didn't execute in sql server 2008

Comment: I'll wait for the question ;)  Running totals are much easier in SQL Server starting with 2012 or Oracle.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  I had a really neat cumulative distribution function that works great.  Going to try to see what I can do for this one.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `JOIN` the tables in that manner.  You would either need to create a view that you reference twice or you can do the following:

```
SELECT row_number() over(order by patientid, admissiondate, claimsfromdate, rehabWait) as rn
    , x.patientid
    , x.admissiondate
    , x.claimsfromdate
    , x.rehabwait 
FROM 
(
    SELECT distinct 
            c1.patientid
            , c1.admissiondate
            , c1.claimsfromdate
            , DATEDIFF(dd, c1.admissiondate, c1.claimsfromdate) as rehabWait
            , c1.hcpcs
    FROM    Claims c1
    INNER JOIN Claims c2
        ON c1.patientid = c2.patientid
    WHERE  c1.hcpcs in ('g0151', '97001', '97002', '9339') and c1.claimsfromdate > c1.admissiondate
) x
```